# iOS: Could not update UI elements from hittest() method swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am having a parent view **ViewA** and a **tableview** as a subview inside viewA.
The viewA have fixed frame and size. The tableview inside has bigger size than viewA hence it goes beyonds the viewA frame.
I need to update an UIlabel text which is also a direct subview on viewA, when a tableview cell is selected.
Hence I am overriding hittest() method in the viewA to detect the tableview cells selection which are falling beyond the viewA frame. It is working perfectly and I do receive the tableview didselectrow call.
But I am facing issues on updating the UILabel when the cell outside the ViewA frame is selected. But it works when the cell inside the ViewA frame is selected.

The image below is how the view actually looks like.

[image]

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        for subview in subviews.reversed() {
            let convertedPoint = subview.convert(point, from: self)
            if let hitView = subview.hitTest(convertedPoint, with: nil) {
                return hitView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       
        self.updateTitle(self.viewModel.dataSource[indexPath.row])
    }

func updateTitle(_ title: String) {
        radarDataTitle.text = title
    }
```

Comment: Hit test?  Where are you writing code?  Inside a view controller?

Comment: Not in VC. Hit test was written in a View’s subclass. Table view delegates were also in the same view’s subclass only.